# Record system audio with Visual Basic.Net

Tags: vb.net, winapi, audio, dll, audio-recording

I have been stuck on a issue about recording system audio in VB.Net for quite some time now. And I can't find any proper ways to do it. I have been able in the past to make it record the Stereo Mix channel. But as we all know: The quality is absolutely horrible.

I have looked into the [Bass.net](http://bass.radio42.com/) library, but find it incredibly hard to understand. And the licensing agreement does not fit my usage.

Is there a way to have it record the system audio (Audio played by the computer) properly with optimal audio quality where I can save the recorded audio as a .wav or .mp3?

Comment: @alexanoid It looks nice and all, but the license costs $740 USD for one single license. NAudio did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[naudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) can do that and is disstributed under the Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL). Don't know if the licenses fits your needs but at least naudio will

Comment: Could you please show me some examples? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation about system sound recording...

Answer (score 0):

This will help you accomplish what you need with no third party libraries required.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/770246/How-to-record-any-PC-sound-through-WASAPI-and-Audi

Comment: It looks like I will need a licensed library named **Audio Sound Recorder for .NET** for it to work. That is not an option here, sorry.

Comment: Audio Sound Recorder is only used to make interfacing with the WSAPI easier. It is by no means essential and the code in that article will accomplish what you need without the Audio Sound Recorder library. Just read the article you have no need to download the project, the first three snippets will give you what you need.

Comment: I am pretty sure those snippets are using the mentioned API. Already on the first snippet: `... nReturn = audioSoundRecorder1.InitDrivers ...`. I also tried to download the example solution, but it doesn't even compile properly. Could you maybe show me an example without using the API?